# Preimage, surjection, and injection for f: Z x Z -> Q, f(m, n) = m/(|n| + 1)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $f\colon \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Q$, $\ f(m, n) = \frac m{|n| + 1}.$

I need to define the preimage of $f^{-1}(\{0\})$. The way I understand that means that I need to find all the values that would give $f(m, n)$ the value $0$. I'm not sure if this is correct though. If it is, then there would be infinite values, so long as the numerator and denominator are equal.

The I need to determine whether or not $f$ is an injection and a surjection and prove why.

Would it be correct to say that $f$ is not an injection because for example, if $m = 2$ and $n = 2$, then $f(m, n) = 2/3$. If $m = 2$ and $n = -2$, then $f(m, n) = 2/3$. So $f(m, n)$ can have the same value with two different inputs, which means it is not an injection.

As for being a surjection - would it  be correct to say that it is a surjection because the function can have any value depending on m and n. This seems like a very feeble "proof", but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ consists of all ordered pairs $(m,n)$ such that $f(m,n)=0$. Setting 
$$\frac{m}{|n|+1}=0
$$
the solutions are all $(m,n)$ such that $m=0$ (no restrictions on $n$).

You injection argument is correct.

For surjection, it helps to write out the whole statement with quantifiers in their correct place and with all elements properly named: for any $\frac{k}{l} \in \mathbb{Q}$ there exists $(m,n) \in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(m,n)=\frac{k}{l}$. Put another way, given two integers $k$ and $l$, with $l \ne 0$, find two integers $m,n$ such that 
$$\frac{m}{|n|+1} = \frac{k}{l}
$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: The only restriction for n would be that it has to be an element of Z? I'm not entirely sure if that's what the f: Z x Z -> Q implies. 

I'm not really sure how to continue from the surjection part. m = k and |n| = l - 1 ? I'm not sure how to prove anything with this.

Comment: Yes, that's correct about restrictions for $n$. The symbols "$f : \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}$" are a mathematical sentence whose English translation is "$f$ is a function whose domain is $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ and whose range is $\mathbb{Q}$".

Comment: As for the surjection argument, the proof should be in two cases. In the case that $l$ is positive you are correct, your formulas $m=k$ and $|n|=l-1$ look good, and then all you have to do is to say what $n$ itself is, and the proof is complete in that case. But in the case that $l$ is negative the formulas are incorrect and you'll have to do something else.

Comment: If n is negative then n = -l + 1?

Comment: That doesn't look right. First I would rewrite the rational number $\frac{k}{l}$ in the form $\frac{-k}{-l}$...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why...